# Cement Power Resistor PCB Mounting in Vibratory Environment

Tags: power, resistors, pcb-assembly

I'm looking to use a cement type wirewound power resistor on a PCB. We need the short term peak power capabilities that this type seems to provide. It seems the most common are thru hole type, like these axial and radial type. How would these fair in a vibratory environment? I'm thinking the radial type with the body right on the PCB. Then afix it down with a zip tie or high temp epoxy. Does anyone have experience like this and can comment on best practices?

[image: SQPW715RJ]

[image: SQMW715RJ]

EDIT:
It seems like my original plan was probably a poorly thought out plan. Thank you for the suggestions. There is another option that I've come across that might be better for reliability and for DFM. Using an array of SMT power resistors, like this one, https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1773242&DocType=DS&DocLang=English. I think I like that idea the best so far.

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you about vibration levels it can withstand? Then go and look at a resistor that does have a vibration/shock performance level stated and realize that there might be a world of difference between A and B.

Comment: Consider a power resistor in an aluminum housing with screw-holes.

Answer (score 2):

It should be okay if buttoned down. I've used these in industrial equipment that operates 24/7 with significant vibration.

Buttoning down may be challenging, since the high temperatures will affect things like zip ties. A good grade of epoxy should work, but I think I would prefer something like this (photo from [here](http://www.exledshop.com/d.i.y-parts/resistors/cement-resistor-housing-bracket-small-copy.html):

[image]

What you want to avoid is setting the resistor off the board with long leads (which will keep the board from discoloring and likely reduce the resistor temperature) which could allow the part to hit a resonance with the wrong mechanical excitation and fatigue the leads off.

Some cement resistors ("radial") have more rigid end terminals that set them off the board, but I doubt they would fare well in a really high vibration environment.

You might want to pour some copper under the resistor, especially if you're using low-cost laminate or if the appearance matters.